# Images with their path added in useState not loading in production build

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I made a React app with Vite for my portfolio. There I have buttons that change the image of my known skills when i click them. I have implemented this locally using useState. My website works correctly locally and the images load correctly. But when I build it for production only the images that I have imported as components and added load, but the images in the skills section do not load. I have identified the issue to be that the image path does not translate to the production build directory structure after build so the images are not found. But i dont know how to fix this.

Here is my github repo : https://github.com/coderboy53/portfolio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try putting the images in public folder and build

Comment: @Kaneki21 thanks putting the images in the public folder worked like a charm. I just have to add them everytime i build because npm run build removes them otherwise.

Comment: `npm run build` won't remove them but before build you have to keep them in `public` folder, please feel free to accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the images under `public` folder should solve the issue

You can keep the images under `public/images`